# Why is SQL not matching anything?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm running a query on a MySQL database

```
SELECT * FROM t_college WHERE NAME="CEPT University"
```

Even though the entry `CEPT University` exists in column `name`, no match is found.

This is same for every other multi-word `varchar` entry in the database. If the value to be matched is a single word like `xyz`, it finds a match but not for multi word ones.

Comment: Are you sure you are matching exactly the same string? Maybe there are multiple spaces, or non-breaking spaces, or tabs in between words?

Comment: I use `SqlYog` . I'm copying the string from the column directly using the GUI so it has the be the exact same string. And yea I checked.

Comment: Are you using the same database (also check case, try ``show databases``)?

Comment: Can you create a reproduction over at http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Please add a minimal database extract (structure + data).

Comment: I checked and there seems to be a some special character after the last word in the field. If I run the query as `SELECT * FROM t_college WHERE NAME LIKE "CEPT University%"` , it gives  a match. But whatever the character is, its not shown so I dont know what it is.

Comment: you could find out that last character with something like this maybe: `SELECT Title, ASCII(SUBSTRING(NAME, LEN(NAME), 1)) FROM college WHERE NAME LIKE "CEPT University%"`,  or use `HEX` as desribed below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clearly have some whitespace characters (tabs, newlines, etc) other than space characters in your data.

The best approach usually to clean it up. To help debug the problem, use `HEX()`:

```
select HEX(name)
from t_college
```

This will show each character as a two hexadecimal characters in the range `00` to `FF`.

You should be able to figure out what the unwanted characters are, and when you dr delete them by replacing them with a blank.

Comment: Select this cus it helped figure out which character it was

Answer (score 1):

So maybe try to update this column to replace your current values with trimmed ones - use TRIM() function to remove trailing and leading spaces and then try to make this SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

try the below `Query`

```
SELECT * FROM t_college WHERE NAME like '%CEPT University%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you think you should be getting a result from a query you can issue a less strict query than equality and/or use a regex with like/rlike.

SELECT * FROM t_college WHERE NAME like "%CEPT%University%"

If this returns a result you know that your data is not quite formatted how you had specified.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this could be the fact that the string 'CEPT University' might have been stored with unwanted characters or in uppercase or lower case and not exactly as you're trying to find. For instance, you may user the function UPPER('CEPT University') to search it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I finally removed the special character using the query :

`UPDATE t_college SET NAME=REPLACE(REPLACE(NAME, '\n', ''), '\r', '')`.

Hope it helps someone.